# Calculate position of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, paging

I'm working on a simple PDF reader, on the bottom I have a `UIScrollView` with all the pages, in the middle I have a label which should show the page numbers while you're scrolling thru.

But I can't figure out how to calculate the exact position and see what page is in the middle.
I also have 2 types of PDFs, once is a double paged PDF and the other one is just a single side.

This is the way I'm drawing them in the scrollview

```
NSInteger xPos = 20;
for(int i = 0; i < [pdf numberOfPages]; i++)
{
    ThumbViewController *tmpThumb = [[ThumbViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil page:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i + 1] andPDF:pdf];

    // SINGLE SIDE PDF
    if([_issue.presentation isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        tmpThumb.view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 5, 150, 200);

        xPos += 200;
    }
    // DOUBLE SIDE PDF
    else
    {
        tmpThumb.view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 5, 150, 200);

        // Draw double pages
        if((i % 2) == 1)
        {
            xPos += 105;
        }
        else
        {
            xPos += 140;
        }
    }

    [_scrollView addSubview:tmpThumb.view];

    [tmpThumb release];
}
```

Which gives me these nice thumbnails:
[image]
[image]

But I'm stuck on the next part, when scrolling thru the `UIScrollView` I can't find any good way on how to calcule which page is in the middle of the view, currently I tried this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Calculate what page is in the middle
    NSInteger contentSize = scrollView.contentSize.width / [_readerModel.pdf numberOfPages];
    NSInteger pageNumber = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / contentSize);

    // Single side
    if([_issue.presentation isEqualToString:@"1"]) pageNumber = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / contentSize);

    NSLog(@"%d / %d", contentSize, pageNumber);

    _thumbnailPopup.titleLabel.text = [_readerModel getTitleForPage:pageNumber inIssue:_readerModel.currentIssue];
    _thumbnailPopup.pageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageNumber];
}
```

As you can see from the picture, the pages don't really match up (they accidentally do in the 2nd pic, but when you scroll further they don't)
Does anyone have any experience with something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get back at this, I finally found a decent solution.

When creating the thumbnails I saved all the positions in an array, when scrolling I just check if the position matches.

I know this is not ideal, but calculating the position on the fly was a little hard because I have different sizes of thumbnails.

```
NSInteger scrollPos = scrollView.contentOffset.x + (scrollView.frame.size.width / 2);

for(NSDictionary *tmpDic in _thumbsPos) {
    NSInteger startPos = [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"start"] intValue];
    NSInteger endPos = [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"end"] intValue];
    NSInteger page = [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"page"] intValue];

    if(scrollPos >= startPos && scrollPos <= endPos) {
        _thumbnailPopup.titleLabel.text = [_readerModel getTitleForPage:page inIssue:_readerModel.currentIssue];
        _thumbnailPopup.pageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (page + 1)];

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to calculate the size of a single page and divide the scrollView.contentSize.width by that.

> CGFloat sizeOfAThumbnailPage = ((spaceLeftOfThumbnailPage / 2.0f) +
>   sizeOfThumbnailPage +(spaceRightOfThumbnailPage / 2.0f));
>
> NSInteger pageNearestMiddle =
>   (NSInteger)(roundfscrollView.contentSize.width /
>   sizeOfAThumbnailPage));

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to use [hitTest::](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest%3awithEvent%3a) to get the subview in the center, the real problem is dividing space but it might be handled if you have it as a part of page preview.

Comment: That means that every time I scroll, I would have to do a hittest on all thumbnails right?

Comment: no, you do hitTest at the center point of the scrollview which is one line of code. But the spaces between thumbnail must be the part of them as otherwise you will not get the thumbnail when the dividing space is centered.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't I have to match every thumbnail to that point?

Comment: No, you will have the centered thumbnail as the result of a single method call against the scrollview: `[scrollview hitTest:centerPoint withEvent:nil]` should return you a single centered thumb. Isn't that what you need ?

Comment: Aha, let me try that, I thought I would have to go thru every thumbnail and see if it touches the center point

Comment: Strangely this works with the first thumbnails that are being displayed, but once I start scrolling this returns `(null)`

Comment: Can you set zero spacing between pages to test how it goes ?

Comment: Same problem, it seems that once it goes to thumbnails that start outside the screen it returns `(null)`

Comment: Got the same result myself, it will probably be more effective to use the solution from Michael or you can try to manually use `pointInside:withEvent:` for every thumbnail.